# MySQL LIMIT 1 returns null values

Tags: mysql

Banging my head on this one and not sure how to resolve.  I need to return 1 row per teamcode from the teams tables (distinct values) that includes  user information.

Table users can have multiple values bases on the team code but I need it to only return 1 (any one, it doesn't matter which). I've tried:

```
SELECT a.teamcode, a.area, c.uniqid, c.fullname, c.email
FROM teams a
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT uniqid, CONCAT(first_name,  ' ', last_name ) AS fullname, email, teamcode from users LIMIT 1) c
on a.teamcode = c.teamcode
WHERE a.area= 'ZF15'
```

Ive also tried max:

```
SELECT a.teamcode, a.area, c.uniqid, c.fullname, c.email
FROM teams a
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT max(uniqid) as uniqid, CONCAT(first_name,  ' ', last_name ) AS fullname, email, teamcode from users) c
on a.teamcode = c.teamcode
WHERE a.area= 'ZF15'
```

But the sub query returns null values from the users table.  However, when I remove limit and max, I get the users table values but I get multiple rows per team code. Any ideas?

Comment: I guess it's not the closing ' ?

Comment: Why the JOIN on a tmp table? Why not an actual JOIN and a  GROUP BY? `LIMIT 1` in a subquery is usually the sign of an imperfect query.

Comment: Thanks - yeah it was a typo on the copy and paste. The trailing ' was included on the query itself.  The query executes but returns null values for columns form the users table.

Comment: Have you tried group by?
`SELECT a.teamcode, a.area, c.uniqid, c.fullname, c.email
FROM teams a
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT uniqid, CONCAT(first_name,  ' ', last_name ) AS fullname, email, teamcode from users) c
on a.teamcode = c.teamcode
WHERE a.area = 'ZF15' GROUP BY a.teamcode `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work, joining users on itself on the max(uniqid) per team:

```
SELECT a.teamcode, a.area, 
   c.uniqid, CONCAT(c.first_name,  ' ', c.last_name ) AS fullname, c.email
FROM teams a
   LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT MAX(uniqid) maxuniqid, teamcode
      FROM users 
      GROUP BY teamcode
   ) u on a.teamcode = u.teamcode
   LEFT JOIN users c on c.teamcode = u.teamcode 
       AND c.uniqid = u.maxuniqid
WHERE a.area= 'ZF15'
```

This gets the max(uniqid) from the users table, grouped by the teamcode (1 for each team).  Then joins back to the users table to get the name and email for that user.

Comment: `c.fullname` doesn't exist, but the rest sounds plausible. Do you just make that up without trying?

Comment: That works, thanks Sgeddes. Now I just need to edit to include fullname.  Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: @Aaron -- np, glad I could help!  Sorry about not seeing the CONCAT to get the full name, but as you said, easy enough.

Comment: @Rudie -- thanks, edited answer above.  Wasn't thinking about that, just the OPs issue.